# Loop Collection Into Model Return Duplicate MongoDB PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, object, model

iam new on mongo db, and now im find a problem when i loop the collection into array and add into model the first row always replaced with the last row, and i dont know why.

this my code

```
   class admin{
   protected $_id;
   protected $username;
   protected $firstname;
   protected $lastname;

   public function getAllDocument(){
      $mongo = new \MongoClient();
      $content=[];
      $mongoConnection=$mongo->selectDB("db")->selectCollection("admins");
      $cursor = $mongoConnection->find();
      foreach ($cursor as $key => $value){
           foreach ($value as $index=>$data){
             $this->$index=$data;
            }
           array_push($content,$this)
      }
      print_r($content);
        }
       }
```

when im dumping the array  each loop the records was right, but when out of the loop the record always be the last record repicated.
anyone know to solve my issue, iam very appriciate

Comment: I solve the problem with create new entity at the first loop

Comment: This appears to be a low-value question with no chance of an answer that future SO readers will find helpful.  Please delete this question so SO's list of unanswered questions will be reduced.